# todotxt color not working on iTerm2

Tags: terminal, macos, iterm, color

Is anyone here using todotxt and iterm2?

I'm having a weird issue. When using default terminal app in OSX, my todotxt color is working just fine.

[image: default terminal app]

But when I switch to iterm2, the color is not displayed correctly.

[image: iterm2]

I've changed color Report terminal type to xterm-256color and maxed out minimum contrast, but it still not working. BTW, I'm using oh-my-zsh as my shell. Anybody know how to fix it?? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn minimum contrast back down—that's what's washing out the colors. It's meant to increase the contrast between foreground text and background color, which is making the colors look wrong.